# Align boxes with flexbox and center them 2 by 2

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I almost finish my website but I have one more issue,
At 745px the filter boxe is looking wrong.

[image]

I would like to have it like this

[image]

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .bloc-filtres {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .bloc-filtres ul {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="bloc-filtres">
  <p id="titre-filtre">Filtres</p>
  
  <ul>
    <li class="filtres">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-money-bill-wave"></i>
      <input type="checkbox" id="eco" name="filtre-possible" value="eco" />
      <label for="eco">Économique</label>
    </li>
    <li class="filtres">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-person"></i>
      <input type="checkbox" id="famille" name="filtre-possible" value="famille" />
      <label for="famille">Familial</label>
    </li>
    <li class="filtres">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
      <input type="checkbox" id="romantique" name="filtre-possible" value="romantique" />
      <label for="romantique">Romantique</label>
    </li>
    <li class="filtres">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-dog"></i>
      <input type="checkbox" id="animaux" name="filtre-possible" value="animaux" />
      <label for="animaux">Animaux autorisés</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code!?

Comment: I added the code, you already have the whole code on the github as well, sorry for that !

Comment: Does the demo above accurately show the problem? Please revise as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a few lines to your CSS rule:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
.bloc-filtres ul {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is great! But in this case i would prefer gridsystem. Why? Because you have already a fix structure and dont need the advantages from flexsystem (`flex!`). Below you can see a grid example.

```css
.listing {
  max-width: 768px;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%, 250px), 1fr));
}
.listing div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="listing">
  <div>Box A</div>
  <div>Box B</div>
  <div>Box C</div>
  <div>Box D</div>  
</div>
```